# Dúvida de como alterar o tipo do jquery mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom estou usando o plugin jquery mask no input valor.
A formatação que estou usando é a seguinte '0,000'. Queria saber como alterar a formatação para '0,000' quando eu selecionar KG no 'select'.

```js
$('.valor').mask('00.000.000,00', {
  reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.3/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='valor' name='valor'>

<select name='categoria' class='select form_campos'>
  <option value='1'>R$</option>
  <option value='2'>KG</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode verificar na condição [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do jQuery, e alterar a mascara:

```js
$('.valor').mask('00.000.000,00', {
  reverse: true
});
$("[name=categoria]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $('.valor').mask('00.000.000,00', {
      reverse: true
    });
  } else {
    $('.valor').mask('0,000', {
      reverse: true
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.3/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='valor' name='valor'>

<select name='categoria' class='select form_campos'>
  <option value='1'>R$</option>
  <option value='2'>KG</option>
</select>
```

Comment: muito bom, era isso mesmo que eu queria fazer. Obrigado

Comment: @HugoBorges se a resposta do LucasCosta resolveu o seu problema, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como solução para que outras pessoas sejam ajudadas!

Comment: Bem lembrado, obrigado @JuniorNunes!

Comment: esta esperando o tempo hahaha